# Django not playing nicely with simple angularjs, not sure why

Tags: javascript, python, django, angularjs

So heres my simple angular app. When I run the html file on its own via the browser, the variable name is displayed saying "nothing". However when I integrate it into django by making a dummy view that just calls a template (see views below), no variable name is shown. The only differece is when using django I load the JS files via {% static %} . The html output is the exact same for both except the django version doesn't output the variable name. I have broken the problem down to its simplest form and can't seem to understand what's happening here.

JS files are 100% loaded in django version. Chrome console shows no errors. I originally developed a simple app in angular to integrate with my django app but I can't do anything if this simple issue stands in my way.

views.py

```
def home_tester(request):
    return render(request, 'angular/base.html')
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ZeTasty">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Learning AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="gridfilter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content" ng-controller="GridFilter">
        {{name}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('ZeTasty',[]);
```

gridfilter.js

```
app.controller("GridFilter", function($scope){
    $scope.name = 'nothing';
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add `{%verbatim%}` and `{%endverbatim%}` tag

django and angular use the same `{{` and `}}` markers.
by hinting django with `{%verbatim%}`, he will ignore the `{{` and `}}`. this will allow you to combine angular with django templates

example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ZeTasty">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Learning AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="gridfilter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>


<!-- 'verbatim' is required in order to disable Django's template engine
so we could use Angular's syntax -->

{%verbatim%}
    <div id="content" ng-controller="GridFilter">
        {{name}}
    </div>

{%endverbatim%}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dude I love you!! You have no idea how long I spent trying to figure this out. I don't know how I didn't come across anywhere that this had to be done. Not even in django-angular docs. I just assumed that because Im not sending any context to the template, it would just use the js stuff. Clearly that's not the case. Thanks again !!